# Error in catching 4 character words in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

Learning perl, m trying to catch the 4 character words in a user given file, below is the `while loop` which carries the `regex` patten match

Code Snippet

```
while(<data>)
{
  $caps_string = $_; #assigning data to variable
  print "This is default string :\n $caps_string \n\n"; 

  $caps_string =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;  #lower to upper case
  print "This is caps string :\n $caps_string \n\n"; 

  $caps_string =~ /\b[a-z]{4}\b/ig; #capturing 4 character words - which fails
  print "4 digit words in string are : \n $caps_string \n\n"; 

}
```

**Output :**

```
This is default string :
 This is a text file data, coming from input.txt #correct

This is caps string :
 THIS IS A TEXT FILE DATA, COMING FROM INPUT.TXT #correct

4 digit words in string are : 
 THIS IS A TEXT FILE DATA, COMING FROM INPUT.TXT #incorrect according to me
```

expected output for last line :

```
 #exact 4 character words
     THIS TEXT FILE DATA FROM
```

The Regex pattern and the test string which i am trying, shows output as [expected on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tS6hQ9)

What's wrong in the pattern when using in perl, please guide!!

Comment: Can you try the solution that I have posted below

Comment: In your current solution, you would want to capture all the 4 character words in an array... and then print that array as your output... what you are doing now is just matching the input against the pattern.. but you are not storing the actual matches any where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a regex capture with `()`:

```
$caps_string =~ /\b([a-z]{4})\b/ig;  # Note the case-insensitive matching with /i
```

And then you most probably want to store the matches as well:

```
my @fours = $caps_string =~ /\b([a-z]{4})\b/ig;  # 'THIS', 'TEXT', 'FILE', ...

print "@fours";   # "THIS TEXT FILE DATA FROM"
```

---

Comment: wont `$caps_string =~ /\b([a-z]{4})\b/g;` store the matches of words in `$caps_string` as a single string like `tr` does after transforming??? asking because, `tr` is saving it, so i was thinking that `regex` would also replace it!!!

Comment: @NoobEditor : If you want to modify the string, use `s///`

Comment: i tried `$caps_string =~ s/\b[a-z]{4}\b/ig/;  print "4 digit words in string are : \n $caps_string \n\n"; ` but still i get whole text...mind correcting me again?? :)

Comment: @Zaid You do not need the capture groups here. If you have no capture groups the `//g` called in list context returns all found matches. Capture groups are only needed if you want to capture something that is not the whole match. Of course, this only works because the `\b` are not actually characters but assertions. If you had used white-space characters instead, then the capture group would have helped to not capture those white-spaces with the rest.

Comment: @NoobEditor What s/this/that/ does, is that it replaces instances of "this" with "that". Similar to tr/// but for entire patterns. If you want to capture your actual matches, you already got the two answers for that. Either specify a capture group or store the return value of your matching operation.

Answer (score 3):

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/perl
 $caps_string = 'This is a text file data, coming from input.txt';
 print "This is default string :\n $caps_string \n\n";

 $caps_string =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;  #lower to upper case
 print "This is caps string :\n $caps_string \n\n";

 ## You already converted string to upper case 
 ## So your pattern needs to match upper case letter .. so [A-Z] 
 ## And then you would want to store all the matches in an array   
 @matches = $caps_string =~ /\b[A-Z]{4}\b/g; #capturing 4 character words 
  print "4 digit words in string are : @matches \n";
```

Output I am getting:

```
This is default string :
 This is a text file data, coming from input.txt

This is caps string :
 THIS IS A TEXT FILE DATA, COMING FROM INPUT.TXT

4 digit words in string are : THIS TEXT FILE DATA FROM
```